# Basic MongoOperations call returning zero

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Just started using MongoDB with JAVA.

Set up the following JavaObject

```
package com.foo.bar

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "cameras")
public class Camera {

    @Id
    private int id= -1;
    String name = "";
    String orientation = "";
    boolean tempdis = false;
    int refreshRate = -1;
    String cityCode = "";
    String provider = "";
    Location location;
    //Gets & Sets Below
}
```

I then have the following config

```
package com.foo.bar.config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig {

    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "myDB");
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;

    }

}
```

And in my main application

```
package com.foo.bar

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import com.foo.bar.config.SpringMongoConfig;
import com.foo.bar.Camera;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                SpringMongoConfig.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx
                .getBean("mongoTemplate");

        List<Camera> listUser = mongoOperation.findAll(Camera.class);

        System.out.println(listUser.size());

    }
}
```

Running this code is getting me a size of 0.  However, in the command line I get the following

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
> use myDB
switched to db myDB
> db.Camera.count()
1018
>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Document(collection = "cameras")
public class Camera {
```

`Camera` is mapped to collection `cameras` in your code.

and you are looking up in collection `Camera` using `db.Camera.count()`